# Text editor with split screen option

Tags: editors, window

Is there an editor which has the option to "split the screen" into two or more parts, accessing more than one file (possibly with a file tree) without opening more editor windows at once, and how would one do this (what are the commands).

I don't know if I made myself clear, but "split screen" is the only way to describe what I want to achieve. I want to use it to program, having more than one file open for editing. Note that I'm pretty new to both vi and emacs, if these are capable of doing this. Also, if this has to be done through a terminal editor, can it be done in the same terminal, regardless of the screen size?

Comment: I know you asked specifically about editors and not terminals, but I think it is worth to note for future visitors: the terminal emulator `terminator` also has the feature of split screen: `ctrl + shift + e` will split vertically and `ctrl + shift + o` will split horizontally (and also `ctrl + shift + t` will open a new tab)

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós I'll keep that in mind, thanks!

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós: You can also use a multiplexer like screen or tmux to achieve that in other terminal emulators. Disadvantage, of course, is that you have to remember to run them first, but the flexibility is probably worth it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`vim` can easily do that:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> - Split windows

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> - switch between windows

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> - Quit a window

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> - Split windows vertically

```
:sp filename
```

will open `filename` in new buffer and split a window.

You can also do

```
vim -o file1 file2
```

To open the files in a split screen layout. Replace `-o` with `-O` for vertical split instead of horizontal.

Comment: Or type `:help CTRL-W` to see all the split window operations.

Comment: Wow, great! I also stumbled upon ":split", but it only splits horizontally. Can you please just include which version of vim this is? Thanks!

Comment: @Eve I use VIM (Vi IMproved) 7.3.

Comment: I would create a mapping like `map <C-left> <C-W><left>` for each of the directions to ease switching windows.  I use a mapping lie that except with the `hjkl` keys for movement but if you do pick vim it might be some time before you're ready to use those.

Comment: @Eve - you can also use `:vsplit` to create a vertical split, and as with `:split` it accepts a filename or command

Comment: And like `<C-w>h`/j/k/l will move between windows in specific directions, `<C-w>H`/J/K/L (capitalized) will move the window in that direction.

Comment: My vim is 7.2.xxx. I'll update it and give those a try thanks.

Answer (score 13):

This can be done using Emacs. It works in GUI and in terminal mode. You can even split multiple times. Here are some basic key combinations:

> **C-x 2** 
>       Split the selected window into two windows, one above the other (split-window-below).
>   **C-x 3** 
>       Split the selected window into two windows, positioned side by side (split-window-right).
>   **C-Mouse-2** 
>       In the mode line of a window, split that window.

Source: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Split-Window.html

Comment: For anyone unfamiliar with *Emacs* terminology, it is worth noting that an Emacs *window* is what many other editors call a *screen* or a *panel*. An Emacs *frame* is what others call a *window* (it is called a *frame* because the *windows* within it are *framed* either by the desktop decoration (title-bar and borders) or by the terminal... *Windows* contain *buffers* (some text; usually a file).

Comment: @Peter.O - Not just for those unfamiliar with Emacs... I have been using Emacs for over 5 years and would not have been able to explain the differences. I just use it.

Answer (score 11):

With vim, you can use `split` or `vsplit`.

The first one will split horizintally and the second one will split vertically.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> then to navigate through split screens.

You can also use tab. `tabnew filename` will open filename in a new tab. You can use `tabnext` and `:tabprevious` to navigate between tabs.

I personnaly maps the left and right arrows to navigate between tabs:

```
map <right> :tabnext<CR>
map <left> :tabprevious<CR>
inoremap <right> <ESC>:tabnext<CR>a
inoremap <left> <ESC>:tabprevious<CR>a
```

Comment: Additionally, the NERD_tree plug-in can be use for showing the directory tree in a separate split. (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658)

Answer (score 9):

`joe` ([Joe's Own Editor](http://joe-editor.sourceforge.net/)) can do this, too:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> - split window horizontally

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> - switch to the previous window

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> - switch to the next window

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> - open new file in current window

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> - grow height of current window

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> - shrink height of current window

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> - hide all windows except the current one, press again to show all windows again

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> - close a window

Answer (score 9):

### [Kate](http://kate-editor.org/)

KDE Advanced Text Editor is very featureful.
It has everything you described in the question and [much more](http://kate-editor.org/about-kate/).

See for yourself:

[image: Screenshot]

To split the view, go to *View* → *Split View*. Then you can select one of these options:

- *Split Vertical* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)
- *Split Horizotal* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
- *Close Current View* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

To get the layout like on this screenshot, *Split Vertical*, click on the bottom view and then *Split Horizontal*.

Of course, the boundaries of the views can be changed by dragging the borders (splitters) between them. To switch between the views, use <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.

By the way, Kate has a so-called [VI Mode](http://kate-editor.org/kate-vi-mode/) (*Settings* → *Configure Kate…* → *Editing* → VI Input Mode). Then the shortcuts for view splitting become the same as in Vim (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44531/8155)).

Answer (score 5):

[Sublime Text 2](http://sublimetext.com) can do that (and many more).

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in getting to grips a bit better with VIM, check out [vimcasts.org](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/archive), it has a bunch of really friendly video tutorials. This one especially for [split screen magic](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/working-with-windows/)

Enjoy!

Comment: That's nice, thanks so much! I would up this more, but I'm only allowed one.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding file trees, I personally use NERDtree with Vim. It requires Pathogen. I found the command to open the tree (`:NERDtree toggle`, iirc) to be a bit long, so I remapped it to `<F2>`.
If you're working on a project with lots of files in lots of directories (think Rails projects), it's a really nice.

EDIT:

NERDtree is on Github: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree

This is the remapping I use in my .vimrc: `map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>`

Comment: Thanks, I may have other questions about this. Those I reserve for another time. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I use `tmux` and `vim` for split-screen editing in a terminal-based environment, though you could use any command-line based text editor for this (e.g. `nano`, `emacs` etc.).

`tmux` is short for "terminal multiplexer" and it allows you to create sessions with multiple terminals, running in separate "windows" and also "panes" within these windows, which are what allow you to split the screen. `tmux` is included in the repositories of many Linux and BSD distributions. I find this to be the most flexible option for coding, as I can also add splits and windows that contain terminals where I can compile code and use a version control system, like `git` alongside my code editing.

Here is an example of how I would create a split screen editing session using `tmux` and `vim`.

First open a terminal. In the below commands written after `$` are issued from the command line. This uses the default key-bindings in `tmux`.

1. Start a new tmux session. Here we make one called "coding":

   `$ tmux new -s coding`

   [image: tmux just opened]
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> followed by either <kbd>%</kbd> for a vertical split or <kbd>"</kbd> for a horizontal split.

   [image: vertical split]

   [image: horizontal split]
3. You can move between the splits (or in `tmux` parlance, the "panes") by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> followed by <kbd>o</kbd>.
4. Now open up a text editor with whatever files you want to edit in each pane. Here I have just opened two text files using `vim`, e.g.

   `$ vim file1.txt`

   Switch panes:<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> followed by <kbd>o</kbd>.

   `$ vim file2.txt`

   [image: editing two files simultaneously]

`tmux` is extremely advanced, allowing for multiple panes in a single window arranged in various ways and `vim` allows you to open multiple text files at once in tabs. I tend to use both the tabbing in `vim` and the panes in `tmux` to allow me to edit, version control and debug code simultaneously. If you have time to invest in learning the keyboard shortcuts and features of `tmux` it can be a very powerful development environment.

A `tmux` cheat sheet for starting out: [dayid's screen and tmux cheat sheet](http://www.dayid.org/os/notes/tm.html)

A tutorial on tabs in `vim`:  [Vim tips: Using tabs](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442422-vim-tips-using-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

i personally would use screen or tmux.  both allow you to open multiple panels though i think tmux is better at recovering a multi panel session than screen. you also get the added benefit of being able to attach to the session if you disconnect from you local desktop session and then SSH in.  You even have the ability to share the session with other users as well for collaboration.

Comment: here is a downvote because you dont use shift

Answer (score 0):

Beside `vim`, `emacs` and `joe` editors, here are some others terminal (tty) / x-terminal emulator editors, that can show at least two files at the same time. May be not the cutest Swiss army knives but learning curve seem not too steep in any case:

**1) mcedit**

Is part of Midnight Commander (a text-mode file manager, install it with 
`apt-get install mc` in Debian-based distros).

[image: mcedit]

**2) wpe \ xwpe**

Available with `apt-get install xwpe` in Dedbian distros. However, seem that is a stopped protect.

[image: xwpe]

**3) nfte \ efte**

eFTE is also available via `apt-get install efte`.

[image: efte]

On the other hand, for the X-window there also some GUI "diff" tools that might be useful for this purpose. In my Linux Mint I have at least two:

**4) xxdiff**

A Qt-based application (`apt-get install xxdiff`)

[image: xxdiff]

Not tested and not showed, but exists also `Fldiff` using the Fast Light Toolkit (FLTK)  but inspired partly in `xxdiff`. Also in the official repositories (`apt-get install fldiff` and you can test it yourself). The same apply to `mgdiff`.

**5) kdiff3**

A similar KDE application (`apt-get install kdiff3`).

[image: kdiff3]

Answer (score 0):

You can use github's atom text editor. It comes with split screen functionality.